# not able to convert data type

Tags: java, types

in my `customerInfoForm` i have a field `String DateOfBirth`.

in my `Customer` class, `DateOfBirth` is of type `DateTime`.

in `DataBase` also column type is `DateTime`.

When I call `customer.setDateOfBirth(customerInfoForm.getDateOfBirth);`  It shows error .how to convert this?

Please suggest what to do?

Comment: 1. If you ever have an error, please post text of it here. 2. Please, accept some answers by clicking a tick in the left of the answer.

Comment: `DateTime` is not a built-in class in Java SE. Where does this type come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `DateFormat` object to parse the string version into a Date.

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
customer.setDateOfBirth(format.parse(customerInfoForm.getDateOfBirth()));
```

Note, you talk about `DateTime` which is not the core Java object for dates. If you are using another library (such as joda-time) you will need to use a different formatter.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Date getDate(String dateString, String format) {
                        Date toReturn=null;     
                        try {
            SimpleDateFormat dFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
            toReturn= dFormat.parse(dateString);
            return toReturn;
        } catch (Exception e) {         
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Use this function to convert your Date in String format to a Date object. make sure you pass the correct format.
Eg. of formats (`"MM/dd/yy HH:mm a"` etc)

Answer (score 0):

Have a overloaded method for setDateOfBirth in customer which accepts String and sets as the DateOfBirth as DateTime.